# How to Prevent on item Touch while Scrolling Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i wanted to add touchlistner to Items of Recyclerview.mainly  want to get `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN` for perticuler item of Recyclerview.i added OnItemTouchListner and also tried OnTouchListner in OnBindViewHolder. but when i scroll recyclerview Touchlistner of Item got called. i also try to add Gesture Listner to items. but nothing happend using gesture listner. here some touch listner code,

```
holder.txtView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d("LogTest11","Action_DOWN");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.d("LogTest11","Action_MOVE");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d("LogTest11","ACTION_UP");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Recyclerview scroll listener separately. And for items, use **onClickListener** instead.

Comment: i dont want onClickListner. i want ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. When ACTION_DOWN i ahve to Start mediaplayer to play some sounf. but when release finger  on ACTION_UP i want to stop mediaplayer.

Comment: but currently when i scrolling recyclerview mediasterted playing

Comment: In that case, you can start media on Recyclerview onBindViewHolder. And remove that when another view is focused.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this using handler runnable.

```
 Handler handler =  new Handler();
```

---

```
 holder.txtView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("PrintingLogs","ACTION_DOWN");
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable,500);
                        break;
//                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//                        Log.d("PrintingLogs","ACTION_MOVE");
//                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
//                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        Log.d("PrintingLogs","ACTION_CANCEL");
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("PrintingLogs","ACTION_UP");
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```